# null pointer exception from ws.url() in playframework 2.5.4

Tags: java, web-services, playframework, playframework-2.5

`NullPointerException` in `ws.url()`:

```
WSRequest request = ws.url(url);
```

I am working with play 2.5.4 and Scala 2.11.7 
Testing url is taken as "http: //www. google.com"
Below is code snippet from testing.

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.libs.ws.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class WSApplication extends Controller {

    static String url = "http://www.google.com";
    @Inject 
    static WSClient ws;

    public static CompletionStage<Result> index(){
        WSRequest request = ws.url(url);
        CompletionStage<WSResponse>  wsResponse = request.get(); 
        return wsResponse.thenApplyAsync((r) -> ok(r.getBody()).as("text/html"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add the error stacktrace to your question. This will help others to understand the issue better.

Answer (score 2):

Injection in static fields won't work in Play by default as it is a feature that has to be [activated for Guice](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections#static-injections), the default underlying CDI implementation. This is considered a bad practice though. From the Guice docs:

> Static members will not be injected at instance-injection time. This API is not recommended for general use because it suffers many of the same problems as static factories: it's clumsy to test, it makes dependencies opaque, and it relies on global state.

Use a non-static member instead:

```
@Inject
private WSClient ws;
```

A side note: judging by your code and the static method signature you've declared you are using the deprecated static routes generator of Play. You should consider migrating to the default injected routes generator that was introduced with play 2.4. See the [migration guide for Play 2.5](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration24#Routing) for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved after adding dependency injection in built.sbt

```
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

and scala version of same problem

```
class MainController @Inject() (ws: WSAPI) extends Controller {
    val url = "http://www.google.com" 
    def index = Action.async {
      ws.url(url).get().map(r => Ok(r.body))
   }
}
```